# assign jquery response to div of class name in closest tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the response of jquery in the class 'defects' in the corresponding row where defect_type is selected. The jquery request is working fine and response is received, but is able to display neither in the td part nor inside a div in t.  The code lines i wrote in the success section dont work.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control defect_type" onChange="get_defects(this.value)">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>                                                   
                    </select>
                </td>   
                <td class="defects"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control defect_type" onChange="get_defects(this.value)">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>                                                   
                </select>
            </td>   
            <td class="defects"></td>
        </tr>
    </body>
    <script>    
        $(".defect_type").change(function(){
            if(this.value==""){
                alert("Select Defect Type");
                return;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '../ajax/get_defects.php',
                data: {
                    defect_type: this.value
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.defects').html(response);  
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.defects').text(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect this is a scope issue for `$(this)`.  Try assigning `$(this)` to  a variable before the `AJAX` call, and then refer to it in the `success` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**: the $(this) inside the success function does not refer to the element that changed. It refers to AJAX.

**Solution**: Assign $(this) to a variable and then use the variable instead.

```
    $(".defect_type").change(function(){
        if(this.value=="") {
          alert("Select Defect Type");
          return;
       }

       var me = $(this);  // <-- create the var

       $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: '../ajax/get_defects.php',
           data: {
                defect_type: this.value
           },
           success: function (response) {
               me.closest('tr').find('.defects').html(response);  // <--use the var here
               me.closest('tr').find('.defects').text(response);  // <--use the var here
           }
       });
    });
```